# How To convert Model object list To Data object list in c# implicity

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code in my model:

```
public class Employee:
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my code in my controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    Data.MainDataClassDataContext db =new Data.MainDataClassDataContext();
    public List<Data.Pezeshk> Get()
    {
        var q = from e in db.Pezeshks
                select new Models.Employee
                {
                    Id = e.p_ID,
                    FirstName = e.p_Name,
                    LastName = e.p_Family,
                };
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

and my data class is linq to sql data class, but my problem is in the last line
`q.ToList();` I got this error:

> you can not implicitly convert Model To Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method's signature is `public List<Data.Pezeshk> Get()` 
**while** the list you are constructing contains objects of type `new Models.Employee`.

I assume you want to change this: `public List<Data.Pezeshk> Get()` to this: `public List<Models.Employee> Get()`

And as a side note - Maybe you'd want to return `IEnumerable<Employee>` instead of converting it to a `List`